# Performance hit installing multiple desktop environments in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, desktop-environments

Will installing multiple desktop environments (Gnome, KDE, XFCE, LXDE) on a Fedora laptop slow down the system?

Comment: the answer is .... no. Well at least it didn't affect the performance of my computer with 3 desktop environments.

Answer (score 2):

No, It will not effect the performance of the system. Because only one of them will be working at a time. Other will be reside as library files in permanent storage..